# Android Programming Error using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

```
package com.nrbbearings.nrbappcatalogue;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;

    public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern) {
        this.parentItems = parents;
        this.childtems = childern;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);

        TextView textView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group, null);
        }

        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
```

It is giving the toast but doesnot Intent

```
                //Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                    //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClassName("com.nrbbearings.nrbappcatalogue", "com.nrbbearings.nrbappcatalogue.ThirdActivity");
```

Error here it says to create method startActivity(Intent) and I think its 
because my class extends BaseExpandableListAdapter and not Activity so how do i correct this?

Please help

```
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }
```

Should this be true?

```
    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern) 
{
  this.parentItems = parents;
  this.childtems = childern;
}
```

to

```
public MyExpandableAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern) 
{
  activity = context
  this.parentItems = parents;
  this.childtems = childern;
}
```

then use the `activity.startActivity(i);`

`startActivity` is a method of `Context` class so you need an object of `Context` class to call it

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
 Intent i = new Intent(activity,"com.nrbbearings.nrbappcatalogue.ThirdActivity");
 activity.startActivity(i);
```

You need to pass `context` as First parameter. You already have activity `context` in your `MyExpandableAdapter`.

**Update:** try this way `activity.startActivity(i);` for starting a new `Activity`.

`startActivity` is a method of `Context` class so you need an object of `Context` class to call it.

Comment: No forgive me for divinding into blocks. I have written startActivity(i) as you can see in Third Block but it says to add startActivity(Intent) module despite of that

Comment: Still it says the same!

Comment: @user3686305 i did not understand. what is your problem exactly? and first format your code properly.

Comment: The code i wrote above gives me a error to add startActivity() module in it.

Comment: @user3686305 try this `activity.startActivity(i);`